Angular 17/CdkEditor
In Angular 17, I can't integrate CKeditor into the project. In the component I want to use :

"message": "The component 'CKEditorComponent' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule."

It gives this error but I couldn't solve it. can you help me?
I imported all ts files in order but ultimately I could not display the editor on the screen.
I used the following but it failed:
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="model.description" name="description" id="description"></ckeditor>


The error message says that you're trying to import CKEditorComponent but it's not standalone (a new feature in Angular 15). It's part of a module, so you need to import the module instead.
If you're importing it into a standalone component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CKEditorModule],
  template: `<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="model.description" name="description" id="description" />`,
})
export class FooComponent {}

Or if you're importing it into a module:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { FooComponent } from './foo/foo.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CKEditorModule],
  declarations: [FooComponent]
})
export class FooModule {}

For more information, see the documentation (particularly the Quick Start).

Hello, thank you for your reply,
I have tried these things before, the error it gives when I try again:
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined
at new CKEditorComponent
I couldn't figure it out.

Yep! You should ask a new question about that error and include the code your component is using to create the editor instance.

standalone is a new feature and all components are standalone by default
and in this case, you should add your modules to the component in imports:[]
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CKEditorModule], //<---------- here
  template: `your-component.html`,
})


Hello, thank you for your reply,
I have tried these things before, the error it gives when I try again:
ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined
at new CKEditorComponent
I couldn't figure it out.
